# Filling out a list with for loop

Tags: python

I want to make a simple slot machine. The machine should be 5*3 slots big. There are two items: 0 and 1. 0 means nothing and 1 is a win. My code so far:

```
import random

# slot machine
# [][][][][]
# [][][][][]
# [][][][][]

machine = [
    (), (), (), (), (),
    (), (), (), (), (),
    (), (), (), (), ()
]

for slot in machine:
    random.randrange(2)
```

So in the for loop are generated 15 numbers (0 or 1) and they should go in the slots (tuples).

Comment: Why not just append to an empty list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use list comprehension:

```
machine = [random.choice([0, 1]) for i in range(15)]
```

Sample output:

```
>>> print(machine)
>>> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

If you want a "matrix" instead, you can do the following:

```
machine = [[random.choice([0, 1]) for i in range(5)] for j in range(3)]
```

Sample output:

```
>>> for row in matrix:
...     print(row)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

machine = []
for x in range(3):
    machine.append([random.randrange(2) for i in range(5)])
print(machine)
```

Sample output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

A one liner solution, but harder to read to some people could be:

```
import random
print([[random.randrange(2) for i in range(5)] for x in range(3)])
```